# Screenshot program not working

Tags: c

Working on a Windows 7 servicepack 1 environment with cygwin gcc compiler.

The following program is supposed to take a screenshot and save the file as a .bmp to the file specified. It compiles fine and seems to give a .bmp file in the desired directory but when run seems to create only a 1kb file with no screenshot data in it. If the while loop is given a starting value of while(1), it gives the "Unable to Create Bitmap File" error. I am new to this kind of programming and cannot seem to see why this is.

Any ideas?

(has to be compiled with -lgdi32)

code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void TakeScreenShot(char* filename);

int main()
{
   TakeScreenShot("c:\\Screenshot.bmp");
   return 0;
}

//
// Side Effects:N/A
//
//This code is copyrighted and has// limited warranties.Please see http://
//   www.Planet-Source-Code.com/vb/scripts/Sh
//   owCode.asp?txtCodeId=10754&lngWId=3//for details.//**************************************
// 

void TakeScreenShot(char* filename)
{
   keybd_event(VK_SNAPSHOT, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
   keybd_event(VK_SNAPSHOT, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
   HBITMAP h;        

   OpenClipboard(NULL);
   h = (HBITMAP)GetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP);
   CloseClipboard();
   HDC hdc=NULL;

   FILE*fp=NULL;
   LPVOID pBuf=NULL;
   BITMAPINFO bmpInfo;
   BITMAPFILEHEADER bmpFileHeader;

   do
   {
      hdc=GetDC(NULL);
      ZeroMemory(&bmpInfo,sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
      bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSize=sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
      GetDIBits(hdc,h,0,0,NULL,&bmpInfo,DIB_RGB_COLORS);

      if(bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage<=0)
         bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage=bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth*abs(bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight)*(bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount+7)/8;
      if((pBuf = malloc(bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage))==NULL)
      {
         MessageBox( NULL, "Unable to Allocate Bitmap Memory", "Error", MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
         break;
      }
      bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression=BI_RGB;
      GetDIBits(hdc,h,0,bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight,pBuf, &bmpInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

      if((fp = fopen(filename,"wb"))==NULL)
      {
         MessageBox(NULL, "Unable to Create Bitmap File", "Error", MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
         break;
      }

      bmpFileHeader.bfReserved1=0;
      bmpFileHeader.bfReserved2=0;
      bmpFileHeader.bfSize=sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)+sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER)+bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage;
      bmpFileHeader.bfType='MB';
      bmpFileHeader.bfOffBits=sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER)+sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

      fwrite(&bmpFileHeader,sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER),1,fp);
      fwrite(&bmpInfo.bmiHeader,sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER),1,fp);
      fwrite(pBuf,bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage,1,fp);
   }
   while(0);

   if(hdc)
      ReleaseDC(NULL,hdc);

   if(pBuf)
      free(pBuf);

   if(fp)
      fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Extra: the .png file it seems to create cannot be opened with any image viewing software indicating a corruption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program apparently saves bitmap data it gets from the clipboard. If there is no data on the clipboard, I assume it only saves an empty bitmap. And it writes a file called "Screenshot.bmp", not a .png file.

To put bitmap data on the clipboard, I assume you must press the print screen button first. This saves a screenshot to the clipboard. Now the program can be used to save this clipboard data to a file.

Comment: Excellent. This seems to be right on the money. Though shouldn't the keybd_event(VK_SNAPSHOT, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0); be a simulation of the print screen button pressed? And it is indeed a .bmp file created, that was my bad there.

Comment: I assume the keybd_event() might not work as expected on all versions of Windows. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx says: **Note  This function has been superseded. Use SendInput instead.** I have never used that, but I guess you should investigate that function.

Comment: I have added the SendInput function on this page: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=377393 Thing is when any key suck as VK_CAPITAL is used there, it works correctly, but the VK_SCREENSHOT option is the only one which seems not to work correctly!

Comment: Did you try both options: `GenerateKey(VK_SCREENSHOT, FALSE);` and `GenerateKey(VK_SCREENSHOT, TRUE);`? I don't know if `VK_SCREENSHOT` is extended or not.

Comment: I have and it doesn't seem to work. Here's something bizarre which does seem to work however: If I run it with GenerateKey(VK_SNAPSHOT, FALSE); and keybd_event(VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, 0, 0); one time. The next time if I run keybd_event(VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, 0, 0); only and comment the other thing out, it works! The big question is why since the GenerateKey() function clearly copies to clipboard correctly when used but the program refuses to work with it.

Comment: I don't have a Windows keyboard to try it out, so I can't help you here. I have Windows in a VM on the Mac, but the keyboard is a Mac one.

Comment: Forget the Windows keyboard. It is not required. I tried with C++Builder, and sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. There should be better ways than to send a VK_SNAPSHOT key to the input stream.

Comment: It is a timing issue. I used the `keybd_event` version and added a `Sleep(200);` after it. That seems to work.